# Vue js access data from seperate component , how to?

Tags: javascript, vue.js, components

I wanted to know how can I access pokemon data which is the response from the API from `(api.vue)` component, access it from `api.vue` to `app.vue` and load the data to my choices array.I've tried accessing the data using `'<Api/>'` but is there a better way on getting the data from separate component parse it and load it to an array for example in my app.vue I have choices array. Thank You

## API.VUE

```
 <template>
  <div class="hello">
    {{ pokemon }}
  </div>
</template>

<script>
import axios from 'axios'

export default {
  name: 'HelloWorld',
  data () {
    return {
      pokemon: {}
    }
  },
  created () {
    axios.get('https://pokeapi.co/api/v2/pokedex/kanto/')
      .then(response => {
        console.log(response)
        this.pokemon = response.data
      })
      .catch(err => {
        console.log(err)
      })
  }
}
</script>

<style scoped></style>
```

## APP.VUE

```
<template>
  <div id="app">
    <vue-query-builder
      :rules="rules"
      v-model="query">
    </vue-query-builder>
    <Api/>

    <p>Generated output : {{questions}}</p>

    <pre>{{ JSON.stringify(this.query, null, 2) }}</pre>
  </div>
</template>

<script>
import VueQueryBuilder from "vue-query-builder";
import HelloWorld from "./components/HelloWorld";
import Api from "./components/Api";

export default {
  name: "App",
  components: {
    VueQueryBuilder,
    HelloWorld,
    Api 
  },

  data() {
    return {
      rules: [
        {
          type: "select",
          id: "vegetable",
          label: "Question",
          choices: [
            { label: "Apple", value: "apple" },
            { label: "Banana", value: "banana" }
          ]
        },
        {
          type: "radio",
          id: "fruit",
          label: "Fruit",
          choices: [
            { label: "Apple", value: "apple" },
            { label: "Banana", value: "banana" }
          ]
        }
      ],

       query: {
        "logicalOperator": "All",
        "children": [
          {
            "type": "query-builder-group",
            "query": {
              "logicalOperator": "Any",
              "children": [
                {
                  "type": "query-builder-rule",
                  "query": {
                    "rule": "vegetable",
                    "selectedOperator": "contains",
                    "selectedOperand": "Vegetable",
                    "value": null
                  }
                },
                {
                  "type": "query-builder-rule",
                  "query": {
                    "rule": "fruit",
                    "selectedOperand": "Fruit",
                    "value": "banana"
                  }
                }
              ]
            }
          }
        ]
      }
    };
  }
};
</script>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Return the data `pokemon:[]`, import app vue inside api vue component, then pass the data as props on the html app vue component so you can access it on app vue component like the code below.

API.vue

```
<template>
  <app>
     v-for="poke in pokemon" 
     :key="poke.id"
     :poke="poke">
  </app>

  <div class="hello">
    {{ pokemon }}
  </div>
</template>

<script>
import axios from 'axios'
import APP from './App.vue'

export default {
  name: 'HelloWorld',
  data () {
    return {
      pokemon: []
    }
  },

  components: {
      'app': APP
  },

  created () {
    axios.get('https://pokeapi.co/api/v2/pokedex/kanto/')
      .then(response => {
        console.log(response)
        this.pokemon = response.data
      })
      .catch(err => {
        console.log(err)
      })
  }
}
</script>

<style scoped></style>
```

App.vue

```
<template>
  <div id="app">
    <vue-query-builder
      :rules="rules"
      v-model="query">
    </vue-query-builder>
    <Api/>

    <p>Generated output : {{questions}}</p>

    <pre>{{ JSON.stringify(this.query, null, 2) }}</pre>

     <p>{{poke.id}}</p> // render pokemon data id
  </div>
</template>

<script>
import VueQueryBuilder from "vue-query-builder";
import HelloWorld from "./components/HelloWorld";
import Api from "./components/Api";

export default {
  name: "App",
  components: {
    VueQueryBuilder,
    HelloWorld,
    Api 
  },

  props: ['poke'], // new line of code data from api.vue

  data() {
    return {
      rules: [
        {
          type: "select",
          id: "vegetable",
          label: "Question",
          choices: [
            { label: "Apple", value: "apple" },
            { label: "Banana", value: "banana" }
          ]
        },
        {
          type: "radio",
          id: "fruit",
          label: "Fruit",
          choices: [
            { label: "Apple", value: "apple" },
            { label: "Banana", value: "banana" }
          ]
        }
      ],

       query: {
        "logicalOperator": "All",
        "children": [
          {
            "type": "query-builder-group",
            "query": {
              "logicalOperator": "Any",
              "children": [
                {
                  "type": "query-builder-rule",
                  "query": {
                    "rule": "vegetable",
                    "selectedOperator": "contains",
                    "selectedOperand": "Vegetable",
                    "value": null
                  }
                },
                {
                  "type": "query-builder-rule",
                  "query": {
                    "rule": "fruit",
                    "selectedOperand": "Fruit",
                    "value": "banana"
                  }
                }
              ]
            }
          }
        ]
      }
    };
  }
};
</script>
```

Comment: i think what you mean is ill be importing api.vue to app.vue right? cause the data is from api.vue

Comment: import app.vue to api.vue

Comment: but i wanted to load the data from api.vue to app.vue

Comment: yes you need to import first the app.vue inside api.vue then passing the data pokemon via props inside app component so you can now access the data in app.vue using curly braces follow the code above.

Comment: Can you please provide and example based on my code above? just new to vue , okay2x i will read about props.

Comment: im following your instructions :D

Comment: Im currently implementing it

Comment: property pokemon is not defined

Comment: Also bro i would also like to ask if you how can we parse the data from the api and load it to choices array. thanks

Comment: any data result from the api could be name or anything.

Comment: you need to parse json data from server-side.

Answer (score 0):

Once you start needing components to share and mutate data I would look into a state management library, this will really help you manage all the state in the application, with one source of truth. Otherwise things can start getting messy. ]

Vue has a great library for this based of the redux pattern

https://vuex.vuejs.org/

I would highly recommend it,
Hope that helps :)

Comment: Can you please provide an example solution?